# Create elements in loop and position them, from bottom left to upper right

Tags: c#, winforms, for-loop, object, position

I'm currently working on a chess game and I ran into a problem when drawing the board: the first element is in the top-left corner and the last one is in the lower-right corner.

How can I change my code so that the first element gets generated in the bottom-left corner and the last one in the top-right corner?

My code:

```
 int l = -1;
 for (int x = 0; x < gridSize; x++)
 {
     for (int y = 0; y < gridSize; y++)
     {
         l++;
         points[l] = new Point(tileSize * x, tileSize * y); 
     }
 }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your y loop to start at the max value and work downward.

```
int l = -1;
for (int x = 0; x < gridSize; x++)
{
    for (int y = gridSize - 1; y >= 0; y--)
    {
        l++;
        points[l] = new Point(tileSize * x, tileSize * y); 
    }
}
```

This will go up the first column, then up the second column, etc, until it reaches the top right corner.

[image]